# How to know if song available in a country or not

Tags: android, spotify

How can I find out if a song is available in a country or not so I can enable/disable features of my app based on this information using the Android Spotify SDK or web API.

Comment: from where you input find or enter song?

Comment: All I know is to play a track i pass in the URI but what if I try playing the track in a country where the song isn't available. Will there be an error code or something like that? With Apple Music using their iTunes Search API you can find out if a song is available to stream in a country or not but with Spotify I don't know how to get that information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found web api to solve your problem that provide you a country code,

have look this **https://github.com/spotify/web-api/issues/535** link, this link provide you **available_markets**

**https://labs.spotify.com/2015/03/09/understanding-spotify-web-api/**

[Parse JSON object with multiple levels Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41708171/parse-json-object-with-multiple-levels-android)

Answer (score 0):

Have to use the web-api

I found this forum post that helped me find the answer on a forum post in quora with the title "What website lists Spotify music availability per country"
I would have linked it but I don't have enough reputation to post more than 2 links.

Go to for an explanation of the features available through the web-api
https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/migration-guide/

Can test looking up track availability at this link
https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/console/get-track/#complete